# Conic-sections ellipse

Tags: conic-sections, locus

$ABCD$ is a trapezoid of a fixed big base  $[AB]$ and a small base $[CD]$ of constant length. Find the sets of variable Points C & D such that the sum of $AD + BC$ remains equal to a constant length $l$

I tried using midsegment theory so I can relate [AD] and [BC] for having their sum constant but I reached a deadend or going around a circle!

Comment: I cannot make much sense of this: if $\;AB,\;CD\;$ are the trapezoid's big and small bases, how can the vertices $\;C,\,D\;$ be *variable*? Not only that: if $\;A,\;B\;$ are fixed, whatever the above means it must be that $\;CD\;$ is parallel to $\;AB\;$ ...I can't parse it.

Comment: Points C and D are variable in such a way that [CD] is constant

Comment: (AB) is parallel to (CD)... true

Comment: @AbedShaar: please take a look and see if it is clear. The last was wrong. I misunderstood the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

First, the triangles $ICD$ and $IAC$ are similar.

$$\frac{t}{b}=\frac{p+x}{p}=\frac{q+y}{q}$$

That give us $x=\frac{p(t-b)}{b}$ and $y=\frac{q(t-b)}{b}$, but $x+y=l$, so

$$l=\frac{p(t-b)}{b}+\frac{q(t-b)}{b}=\frac{(p+q)(t-b)}{b} \Rightarrow p+q=\frac{lb}{t-b}$$

And also

$$p+q+x+y=\frac{lb}{t-b}+l=\frac{lt}{t-b}$$

So, we have that $ID+IC=p+q$ is constant and $IA+IB=p+q+x+y$ is also constant.

$I$ belongs to two ellipse, one is stopped (with focus $A$ and $B$) and the other is moving (with focus $C$ and $D$). Those are two intern tangent ellipses intersect at $I$.

So the locus of $C$ and $D$ are the focus of a variable ellipse which is tangent to a stopped ellipse with focus $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Just wow...magnificent...terreffic.. thanks alot!

Comment: you are very welcome. Interesting problem. What is book where did you get that?

Comment: Lebanese education system...I'm from Lebanon in Grade 12 GS (i.e. general sciences specialty in maths and physics)

Comment: The book is translated from french education system. Its name is: Mathematics for general sciences (specialty) for the 3rd year secondary level. Collection: puissance

Comment: No sir, its your job which is nice . Thanks again

Comment: Sorry...but I'm still an amateur in such things. Sometimes I click randomly. I must click the right button?